# installing Windows 10 on external HDD

Tags: 16.04, windows-10

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I need to install win10 on an external HDD.
- the external HDD is not blank, I need to keep the data on it.
- I have the iso file of win10 on the external HDD.
- I can't use DVD or USB flash.
- I am a new user of linux so please I need a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Easyest way is using a virtual environment and running windows in there.
You can install virtual box from this link.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Once you have your virtual box running (type virtualbox in the console), Install what ever OS you desire in what ever storage you desire.

Comment: Yes, that will work for getting a Win10 running but I think the OP means he wants dual boot.